# SWF with flashVars and query string

Tags: string, flash, flashvars

I have a a swf file which is working fine with query string. But at the same time if I pass the values through flashvars it is not working. Is there any difference in the way the values passed between flashVars and query string are handled by SWF?

Note : I don't have the source code of flash and it is an an old one probably in flash 6.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no difference, so you should be able to use flashvars instead of passing them using the querystring.

How to you embed the swf? [Manually using object and embed tag](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html)? If so, make sure you have added the flashvars for both the object and embed. If you use SWFObject to embed, can you show the code?